# Place HTML page into a div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How would I get `window.location` into a div of the same HTML page? Here's what I currently have:

```
function x {
    var httpxml;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    httpxml.open("GET", "Home.aspx", true);
    httpxml.send();

    httpxml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpxml.status == 200 && httpxml.readyState == 4) {

            // what can i write here to show Home.aspx page into div at default.aspx page
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `div` `id` is `div1`:

```
if (httpxml.status == 200 && httpxml.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = httpxml.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery for this. Example:

`$('div.class').load('mypage.html');`

... or:
`$('#mydivID').load('mypage.html');`

Comment: @David Thomas: +1 I aggree. Please stop coming up with libraries everytime. This question is about standard JavaScript. jQuery is not a standard, so we don't want to see it here. Every dumb person can create their library's and then people come to Stack Overflow and ask questions about them. I find that such libraries shouldn't have a tag on this site. This site is meant for *real* programming. Within a few years, only a few people will still know what real JavaScript is.